# Drag-and-drop files from a Zip folder into my window

Tags: c++, zip, windows-explorer

I'm trying to implement a feature when contents of a Zip archive could be dragged-and-dropped from a Windows Explorer's Zip folder into my window. I implemented all necessary methods of IDropTarget and everything works fine when I drag-n-drop regular files from the Windows Explorer.

The issue happens in the following method when I attempt to drag in a file from a Zip folder:

```
HRESULT DragEnter(IDataObject* pDataObject, DWORD grfKeyState, POINTL pt, DWORD* pdwEffect)
{
    static FORMATETC fmtetc_file = {CF_HDROP, 0, DVASPECT_CONTENT, -1, TYMED_HGLOBAL};
    HRESULT hr = pDataObject->QueryGetData(&fmtetc_file);
    if(hr == S_OK)
    {
        //Format supported
    }

    ...
}
```

I get S_FALSE returned from QueryGetData().

Does anyone have any idea what am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't imagine Explorer's zip file handler implements CF_HDROP as that would require it to extract the files before initiating the drag.  I am betting it uses [CFSTR_FILEDESCRIPTOR and CFSTR_FILECONTENTS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776902%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks a lot, using the following lines of code worked for DragEnter():

`FORMATETC fmtetc_file = {RegisterClipboardFormat(CFSTR_FILEDESCRIPTOR), 0, DVASPECT_CONTENT, -1, TYMED_HGLOBAL};
if(pDataObject->QueryGetData(&fmtetc_file) ==S_OK)
{
}`

But now my delimma is how to get the path to either a zip archive (whose file is being dragged into my window) or a temp path to the file itself if the Shell happens to unzip it for me?

Comment: The whole point of drag/drop is to abstract away implementation details like zip files; I would be a little surprised if you could figure that out.

Comment: I'm sorry, Luke, but I still can't figure it out. How am I supposed to get to the file that is dragged into my window then?

Comment: I haven't tested this specifically with the zip folder extension, but I would guess that the FILEDESCRIPTOR structure has the relative path of the archive member (e.g. "folder1\folder2\filename.ext").  The data will be an IStream or possibly an HGLOBAL if the archive member is small.  You will have to copy the file contents from the HGLOBAL or IStream to your destination.

Comment: Thanks. I did some testing and indeed I get an HGLOBAL for each file in the zip archive, except that the data it contains has nothing to do with the actual contents of a file. It looks more like some sort of an internal data structure (like the one for a regular file, when we call DragQueryFile on). So I was wondering, is there an alternative to DragQueryFile() for a Zip archive?

Comment: I just tested this and got one CFSTR_FILEDESCRIPTOR which contained a HGLOBAL (for a FILEGROUPDESCRIPTOR), and for each archive member being dragged I got a CFSTR_FILECONTENTS which contained an IStream.  I am not aware of any simpler API, though 3rd parties have probably written wrapper classes.

Comment: Thanks. I got messed up in STGMEDIUM structs. I posted the code below. Can you check it for me?

Answer (score 1):

I think I got it. Could you review this pseudo-code, I'm not really good at COM:

```
Drop(IDataObject* pDataObject, DWORD grfKeyState, POINTL pt, DWORD* pdwEffect)
{
    FORMATETC fmtetc_file_desc = {RegisterClipboardFormat(CFSTR_FILEDESCRIPTOR), 0, DVASPECT_CONTENT, -1, TYMED_HGLOBAL};
    if(pDataObject->QueryGetData(&fmtetc_file_desc) == S_OK)
    {
        STGMEDIUM stgmed;
        if(pDataObject->GetData(&fmtetc_file_desc, &stgmed) == S_OK)
        {
            if(stgmed.tymed & TYMED_HGLOBAL)
            {
                FILEGROUPDESCRIPTOR* pFGD = (FILEGROUPDESCRIPTOR*)::GlobalLock(stgmed.hGlobal);
                for(int f = 0; f < pFGD->cItems; f++)
                {
                    STGMEDIUM stgmedFile = {0};
                    //You may want to move out the RegisterClipboardFormat() API into some global variable
                    FORMATETC fmtetc_file_desc = {RegisterClipboardFormat(CFSTR_FILECONTENTS), 0, DVASPECT_CONTENT, f, TYMED_HGLOBAL | TYMED_ISTREAM | TYMED_ISTORAGE};
                    if(pDataObject->GetData(&fmtetc_file_desc, &stgmedFile) == S_OK)
                    {
                        BOOL bReadOK = FALSE;

                        if(!bReadOK && (stgmedFile & TYMED_ISTREAM))
                        {
                            //Now read data from a stream & process it
                            //(If need be, it can be saved in a file)
                            IStream *pstm = pStgmed->pstm;

                            //Size of data in a steam & archived file name
                            STATSTG stg = {0};
                            SUCCEEDED(pstm->Stat(&stg, STATFLAG_DEFAULT) == S_OK);

                            //Then to read data from a stream
                            //Call repeatedly until all or required data is read)
                            SUCCEEDED(pstm->Read(pStorage, ncbBytesRead, &ucbBytesRead));

                            //If read and processed successfully
                            bReadOK = TRUE;


                            //Release mem
                            CoTaskMemFree(stg.pwcsName);

                        }

                        //Probably need to implement these as well?
                        if(!bReadOK && (stgmedFile & TYMED_ISTORAGE))
                        {
                        }
                        if(!bReadOK && (stgmedFile & TYMED_HGLOBAL))
                        {
                        }


                        ReleaseStgMedium(&stgmedFile);;
                    }
                }

                ::GlobalUnlock(stgmed.hGlobal);
            }

            ReleaseStgMedium(&stgmed);

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Looks ok to me.  In my testing I only ever saw IStream; not sure if any other storage methods are actually used.  Also, Stat() was returning E_NOTIMPL so you will probably just have to Read() until cbBytesRead == 0.

Comment: Hmm, really. What version of Windows are you testing it on?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I see that for some reason Stat() and Seek() methods don't seem to be implemented on XP. Nonetheless I was able to figure it out and now it works on all platforms -- XP thru Win7.